# TF hub module variables used in preprocessing not exported in Checkpoints during training

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow-estimator, tensorflow-transform

I'm using `tensorflow_transform` to pre-process text data using a [TF Hub Module](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub) and later use the derived features for model training. I tried to provide a minimum working example below.

#### pipeline.py

1) embeds two texts using [NNLM](https://tfhub.dev/google/nnlm-de-dim128-with-normalization/1)
2) calculates the cosine distance between them
3) writes the preprocessed data into a `.csv` file.
4) exports the `transform_fn` function/preprocessing graph to be used later for serving
5) run `python pipeline.py`

```py
    import tensorflow as tf

    import apache_beam as beam
    from tensorflow_transform.beam.tft_beam_io import transform_fn_io
    from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import SetupOptions
    from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
    from apache_beam.io import WriteToText

    import tensorflow_transform.beam.impl as beam_impl
    from tensorflow_transform.coders.csv_coder import CsvCoder
    from tensorflow_transform.tf_metadata import dataset_metadata, dataset_schema

    import tensorflow_hub as hub

    tf_input_raw_feature_spec = {
        'text_1': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        'text_2': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        'y': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.float32),
    }

    SAMPLE_INPUT = [({
        'text_1': 'Help me embed this!',
        'text_2': 'Help me embed this!',
        'y': 1
    }), ({
        'text_1': 'And this as well',
        'text_2': 'Lunch Lunch Lunch',
        'y': 0
    })]

    tf_input_metadata = dataset_metadata.DatasetMetadata(dataset_schema.from_feature_spec(tf_input_raw_feature_spec))


    def tf_transform_preprocessing(inputs):
        outputs = {}

        module = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/nnlm-de-dim128-with-normalization/1")

        text_1_embed = module(inputs['text_1'])
        text_2_embed = module(inputs['text_2'])

        # Calculate Cosine Similarity
        question_normalized = tf.nn.l2_normalize(text_1_embed, 1)
        content_normalized = tf.nn.l2_normalize(text_2_embed, 1)
        outputs['cosine_similarity'] = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(question_normalized, content_normalized),
                                                     keepdims=True,
                                                     axis=1)
        outputs['y'] = inputs['y']

        return outputs


    def run():
        pipeline_options = PipelineOptions()
        pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True

        with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p,\
                beam_impl.Context(temp_dir='./tmp'):

            pcoll_text = p | beam.Create(SAMPLE_INPUT)

            transformed_dataset, transform_fn = (
                (pcoll_text, tf_input_metadata)
                | 'Analyze and Transform' >> beam_impl.AnalyzeAndTransformDataset(tf_transform_preprocessing))

            transformed_data, transformed_metadata = transformed_dataset

            column_names = transformed_metadata.schema.as_feature_spec().keys()

            (transformed_data | ' Write PCollection to GCS, csv' >> WriteToText(
                file_path_prefix='./preprocessed_output',
                num_shards=1,
                coder=CsvCoder(column_names=column_names, schema=transformed_metadata.schema),
                compression_type='uncompressed',
                header=','.join(column_names)))

            transform_fn | 'Write transformFn' >> transform_fn_io.WriteTransformFn('./metadata')


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        run()
```

*Input:*

```
SAMPLE_INPUT = [({
    'text_1': 'Help me embed this!',
    'text_2': 'Help me embed this!',
    'y': 1
}), ({
    'text_1': 'And this as well',
    'text_2': 'Lunch Lunch Lunch',
    'y': 0
})]
```

*Preprocessed Output in `preprocessed_output-00000-of-00001.csv`:*

```
y,cosine_similarity
1.0,1.0000001
0.0,0.1290714
```

#### train.py

1) trains a `tf.estimator.LinearRegressor` on the pre-processed data
2) Periodically evaluates and exports the model using `Checkpoints`
3) During this evaluation it also exports the `serving_input_receiver_fn` that I later want to use for serving it in production. Since I want to feed 
**raw** data to the model while serving, I apply the exported `tf-transform` transformations in the `serving_input_fn`.
4) run `python train.py`

```py
from sys import argv
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_transform as tft
from tensorflow_transform.tf_metadata import dataset_metadata
from tensorflow_transform.tf_metadata import dataset_schema

tf_input_raw_feature_spec = {
    'text_1': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
    'text_2': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
    'y': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.float32),
}

tf_input_metadata = dataset_metadata.DatasetMetadata(dataset_schema.from_feature_spec(tf_input_raw_feature_spec))


def make_input_fn(input_file_pattern, num_epochs, batch_size, label_variable, shuffle=False):
    return tf.contrib.data.make_csv_dataset(file_pattern=input_file_pattern,
                                            batch_size=batch_size,
                                            label_name=label_variable,
                                            num_epochs=num_epochs,
                                            shuffle=shuffle)


def make_serving_input_fn(tf_transform_output):
    tf_transform_output.load_transform_graph()
    raw_feature_spec = tf_input_metadata.schema.as_feature_spec()
    raw_feature_spec.pop('y')

    def serving_input_fn():
        raw_input_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(raw_feature_spec,
                                                                                   default_batch_size=None)
        serving_input_receiver = raw_input_fn()

        # Apply the transform function on raw input
        raw_features = serving_input_receiver.features
        transformed_features = tf_transform_output.transform_raw_features(raw_features)
        return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(transformed_features, serving_input_receiver.receiver_tensors)

    return serving_input_fn


def train(args):
    tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)
    tf_transform_output = tft.TFTransformOutput(args['tf_transform'])

    # model and all outputs under this relative path
    model_dir = './logs/'

    train_input_files = ['preprocessed_output-00000-of-00001']

    tf.logging.info(train_input_files)

    def train_input_fn():
        return make_input_fn(input_file_pattern=train_input_files,
                             num_epochs=args['num_epochs'],
                             batch_size=args['batch_size'],
                             label_variable=args['label_variable'],
                             shuffle=True)

    eval_input_files = ['preprocessed_output-00000-of-00001']

    tf.logging.info(eval_input_files)

    def eval_input_fn():
        return make_input_fn(input_file_pattern=eval_input_files,
                             num_epochs=1,
                             batch_size=args['batch_size'],
                             label_variable=args['label_variable'])

    feature_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key='cosine_similarity')]

    estimator = tf.estimator.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=feature_columns, model_dir=model_dir)

    train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(train_input_fn, max_steps=args['train_max_steps'])

    serving_input_receiver_fn = make_serving_input_fn(tf_transform_output)

    exporter = tf.estimator.LatestExporter(name='model_export', serving_input_receiver_fn=serving_input_receiver_fn)

    eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(eval_input_fn, steps=None, exporters=[exporter], throttle_secs=150)

    tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_spec)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = {
        'tf_transform': './metadata',
        'num_epochs': 10,
        'batch_size': 1,
        'label_variable': 'y',
        'train_max_steps': 1000
    }
    train(args)
```

#### Issue

Whenever I run `train.py` it successfully

- loads the training data
- builds the model
- trains until the first `Checkpoint`,

but always fails when it tries to restore from `Checkpoint` and
   continue training with the following Error message:

```py
NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Restoring from checkpoint failed. This is most likely due to a Variable name or other graph key that is missing from the checkpoint. Please ensure that you have not altered the graph expected based on the checkpoint. Original error:

Key transform/module/embeddings not found in checkpoint
         [[node save/RestoreV2_1 (defined at /.../env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py:924) ]]
```

From what I understand it fails to restore parts of the `TF Hub` module graph used in the preprocessing step (`transform/module/embeddings`). Removing the `exporter` from `eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(eval_input_fn, steps=None, exporters=[exporter], throttle_secs=150)` lets training complete successfully, but obviously doesn't export any `saved_model`.

#### TLDR

How do I use a `TF Hub` module in `tf-transform` preprocessing and apply those data transformations in a `serving` environment in conjunction with a trained model?

#### Appendix

*requirements.txt*

```
apache-beam[gcp]==2.11
tensorflow-transform==0.13
tensorflow==1.13.1
tensorflow-hub==0.4.0
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered in Github. Following is the link, https://github.com/tensorflow/transform/issues/125#issuecomment-514558533.

Posting the answer here for the benefit of community.

Adding `tftransform_output.load_transform_graph()` to `train_input_fn` will resolve the issue. This relates to the way tf.Learn works. In your `serving graph`, it tries to read from the training `checkpoint`, but because you are using materialized data, your training graph doesn't contain the embedding.

Below is the code for the same:

```
def train_input_fn():
        tf_transform_output.load_transform_graph()
        return make_input_fn(input_file_pattern=train_input_files,
                             num_epochs=args['num_epochs'],
                             batch_size=args['batch_size'],
                             label_variable=args['label_variable'],
                             shuffle=True)
```